# Can you give me some book or article recommendations of topology with Kuratowski operators?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm interested in Kuratowski operators but it's really hard to find it in a topology book or articles.  Can you give me some recommendations? If it can be the basic thing I will be enormously grateful.

Comment: As a suggestion, add in the title that you're looking for references including Kuratowski operators. Otherwise this question before being clicked will look like someone asking to learn general topolgy.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will change the title

Comment: At [these web pages](https://www.mathtransit.com/cornucopia.php) Mark Bowron has a huge number of linked papers related to "topological operators". Although his focus is on the Kuratowski 14 closure-complement result, there are many references there relevant for what you're asking about. Also relevant (for the many references provided) is my 3-part answer to [General topological space with closure operation as in Russian translation of Hausdorff's 1914 and 1927 Mengenlehre](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780).